# Trying to install ionic framework on my Mac. ANy idea why?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

```
Lees-MacBook-Air-2:~ yuanhuilee$ node -v
v16.4.2
Lees-MacBook-Air-2:~ yuanhuilee$ npm -v
7.18.1
Lees-MacBook-Air-2:~ yuanhuilee$ sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
Password:
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated ionic@5.4.16: The Ionic CLI now uses ✨ @ionic/cli ✨ for its package name!  https://twitter.com/ionicframework/status/1223268498362851330

changed 716 packages, and audited 717 packages in 23s

42 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details.
```

Any idea what error might this be? I am trying to install ionic framework on my Mac laptop. Thank you.

Comment: Please properly format your console output using code blocks and clarify the question you're asking.

Comment: @JohnD I've edited it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the error logs, it's literally telling you what you need to do:

https://twitter.com/ionicframework/status/1223268498362851330

> Uninstall old Ionic CLI

```sh
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

> Install new Ionic CLI

```sh
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```